# rake test:functionals not working - error MassAssignmentSecurity:error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm following the 4th Ed of Agile Web Dev with Rails. At Chapter 9 pg 112. I'm trying to run rake test:functional. I think I followed every piece of their code but it's giving me a mass assign error. When I run the server, its giving me this error

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in LineItemsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: product

This is how the LineItemsController create function looks like

```
  def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
          notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item,
          status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
          status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the create test in line_items_controller_test.rb in the folder test/functional/

```
  test "should create line_item" do
    assert_difference('LineItem.count') do
      post :create, product_id: products(:ruby).id
    end

    assert_redirected_to cart_path(assigns(:line_item).cart)
  end
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a recent change in the new version of Rails due to the Github fiasco: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b83965785db1eec019edf1fc272b1aa393e6dc57

To fix this you can do one of two things:

1) Change this setting (in your config/application.rb file) to `false` to allow mass-assignment site wide

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

2) Whitelist all the attributes you'll be changing by adding this line somewhere in your model:

```
attr_accessible :product
```

The first is the old default way, and easier.  The second is more secure for production apps.